# How to define WSDL complex type for soap response with list of items

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I`m creating a web service using php soapServer/soapClient class with wsdl. There are some services, which should return list of items. Service returns something like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ...>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getTransactionsResponse>
      <return xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <item>
          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">result</key>
          <value SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[65]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
          <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">id</key>
              <value xsi:type="xsd:int">283</value>
            </item>
            <item>
              ...
            </item>
            ...
          </item>
        </item>
      </return>
    </ns1:getItemsResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But I need to name all elements by attribut name. So something like this:

```
<result>
  <item>
    <attr1>value1</attr1>
    <attr2>value2</attr2>
    ....
  </item>
  <item>
    ...
  </item>
</result>
```

The structure of returned array is:

```
'result' => array
  0 => array
      'attr1' => 'value1'
      'attr2' => 'value2'
      ...
  1 => array
      ...
  ...
```

**EDIT**
My WSDL:

```
<types>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:XYZ">
<xsd:complexType name="Properties">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="attr1" type="xsd:int"/>
    <xsd:element name="attr2" type="xsd:string"/>
    ...
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="transactionsResponse">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="result" nillable="true" type="tns:Properties"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</types>

<message name="getTransactionsResponse">
  <part name="parameters" type="tns:transactionsResponse" />
</message>
```

**Port Type:**

```
<operation name="getTransactions">
  <input message="tns:getTransactionsRequest" />
  <output message="tns:getransactionsResponse" />
</operation>
```

**Binding:**

```
<operation name="getVirtualTransactions">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:getTransactionsAction" />
  <input>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:XYZ" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
  </input>
  <output>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:XYZ" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
  </output>
</operation>
```

I dont know, if I was googling bad, but I could`t find any solution. So I would be glad for some simple example, link to tutorial or documentation, how wsdl should look. Or I have to change hole structure of my array?
Im looking for best practice, how to prepare response as array of items on server side and its wsdl definition.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl didn't help in any direction?

Comment: could you post here, under which keywords I should search it? Maybe I would rather see concrete example.

Comment: Well it was you who wrote in the question that you're creating *with wsdl.*  It's not clear so far with which part of your WSDL you have a problem. You only show the result differences so far. That's why I'm asking. If you came that far, then also put the WSDL definition in here that causes you the trouble otherwise it's hard to say what the alternatives would be. If it's not about writing the WSDL your own please make your question more clear. In any case you should provide a self-containing example that can be easily executed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes you are right. Question isn`t totaly clear, but I hoped, that somebody post proven wsdl corresponding to my array structure. My fault. I added actual wsdl to my question. Will it be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. I just transfer my response array into object and now I get expected soap response form like in my question. Dont know why, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer to your own question. Please consider accepting your answer so others know this has been reqolved